# How to find a specific number in a string of numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking for help with a formula in Excel to find a specific number in a string of numbers.

Our accounting system pulls a report showing numbers from 1 to 10 and each line can have numerous numbers listed in the cell, each separated with a ";".

[image: System example]

What I want to do is create a formula that allows me to simply look for the number in columns O to X (row 3) and fill that number in the corresponding cell.

So starting from row 4, I would like to create a formula that finds each number in the string and simply fills in the one I am looking for in each cell, for example I would like the end result to look like the below example:

[image: Desired look]

If the number doesn't appear then that column is left blank, but if it is found it simply adds itself into the corresponding column.

Hopefully someone out there can help me with this.

Regards;
Greg

Comment: What have you tried? Why does the first row have a 3 in the 2 column? Perhaps FIND/SEARCH formula.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formula in B3

in German:
`=WENN(ISTFEHLER(FINDEN(";" &  B$2 & ";";  ";" &  $A3 & ";"));"";B$2)`

in English:
`=IF(ISERROR(FIND(";" &  B$2 & ";" ,  ";" &  $A3 & ";")),"",B$2)`
[image]

Comment: Hi Chris, I copied the example as seen above into a new excel sheet to test. Unfortunately I get a error message, which says that there is a problem with the formula

Comment: Maybe the error is caused by your language settings: try this ```=IF(ISERROR(FIND(";" &  B$2 & ";" ;  ";" &  $A3 & ";")); "" ;B$2)``` in B3

Comment: @Greg.N see my comment obove

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell `O4`:

```
=IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(O$3,$N4,1))),O$3,"")
```

*Notes*:

1. Assumes your numbers 1 to 10 are in row 3 (i.e `O3:X3`)

Comment: If you use this, you will have a problem with this OP Icon: "2;3;4;5;8;9;10". It will show you that the 1 is included.

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried the above in cell O4 and get an error message saying that there is a problem with the formula. What can it be?